# What's the most efficient way to write large text file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to write a file with some amount of data using this:

```
public static <T extends SomeClass> void writeFile(String buffer, Class<T> clazz, int fileNumber) {
    String fileType = ".txt";
    File file = new File(clazz.getName()+fileNumber+fileType);
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;


    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
        printWriter.print(buffer);//error occurs here
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        System.out.println("created file: "+file.getName());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(printWriter!=null){
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

The buffer string contains +-6mb of data, and when i run the code i get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exactly in buffer.

Comment: Have you given your Java VM a reasonable amount of memory with the -Xmx command line option?

Comment: Did you try writing the buffer in smaller blocks instead of a single call?

Comment: Incidentally, i believe the reason that PrintWriter.write uses memory is that it encodes the whole string into a byte array, and then writes that.

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing `printWriter.print(buffer);` with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 100) {
    int end = i + 100;

    if (end >= buffer.length) {
        end = buffer.length;
    }

    printWriter.print(buffer.substring(i, end);
    printWriter.flush();
}
```

Comment: Programmer's these days are used to having so much memory, they never think about conserving it. Life is about balance.

Comment: @Thom: agree with you, but balance means using as max as resource you have in the right way. ;)

Comment: Balance means using the right amount of resources the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Since 6mb is not so much "data" I think you should increase your java VM memory,

take a look here

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Fix+Out+of+Memory+Errors+by+Increasing+Available+Memory