# Java PrintWriter big memory consume

Tags: java, printwriter

I am trying to write a big file text from DB, around 2 millons of line.
I observed that while PrintWriter is printing (println()) the line, the file size is alway 0 byte. The file have size data after the stream closed.
It cause that all data first save in memory and free it when the stream close.
In my case after 1 millons of data +- 2.5GB of memory consumed. the app crash.
Is possible write data in real time and prevent memory consumition?

This is a a example:

```
    File file = new File("file.txt");

   PrintWriter out;

   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), "UTF-8"));

for (int i=0; i < 9999999; i++){
    out.println("some data here");
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753424/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-write-large-text-file-in-java?

Comment: Why are you complicating the PrintWriter creation? You can just use new PrintWriter("file.txt"); And to answer your question try using flush() every 'n' lines.

Answer (score 1):

You've created the [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-) without automatic line flushing, so the contents will be buffered until you call `flush()` or `close()`. Since you don't want to flush every line (it's slow), you can perform a flush every `N` lines with

```
for (int i=0; i < 9999999; i++){
    out.println("some data here");
    if(i % N == 0)
        out.flush();
}
```

Try it out with different values of `N` to see how the performance changes.

Comment: Hello Kayaman, i tried using out.flush() but not working for me.  And I tried too enable autoflushing using the constructor:   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), "UTF-8"), true);

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? You can see the file size growing as data is flushed.

Comment: The file size is alway 0 byte and memory up to 2.5GB. Only have data size when out.close() execute.

Comment: Then you're not calling `flush()`. You may think you are, but if the bytes aren't being flushed to the file, you're not calling it.

Comment: The flush() is called fine, but the result is the same.

Comment: I observed it. if we execute the program on Windows 7 works fine. but on Windows 2012 that is when i am testing not working.

Comment: Then it's an issue with your environment. That Java code is perfectly valid.

Comment: @toto: which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Hello Gusto2. > jre1.8.0_144 and jdk1.8.0_131 is installed on windows 2012 server.